# Where would you like something picked up

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> And where would you like ***the box picked up*** from? (This is a section of a dialogue between a customer and an agent from a shipping company.)

Is it a reduced sentence? If it is, what is the full version of it?

> And where would you like ***the box to be picked up*** from?

Is that sentence above full version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the verb "to be" is implied. Including it is slightly more formal. Implying it is more casual. To be is also often implied in technical writing for brevity.